# Find derivative of integral functions with exponentiated integration bounds

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, derivatives

I was requested to find the derivative of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, which are defined as follows:

$$f(x)= \int_0 ^{x^2} \frac{e^{t^2} +1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} dt$$

$$ g(x)=\int_\sqrt{x} ^{x^3} \frac{t+1}{\sqrt{1+2^t}} dt$$

I was able to find derivatives of integral functions whose integration bounds were $a$ to $x$, using the fundamental theorem of calculus, but this exponentiated bounds are killing me. How should one proceed to solve such a problem?

Comment: Leibniz rule https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: By the Leibniz rule we get for the first integral $$\frac{2 \left(e^{x^4}+1\right) x}{\sqrt{1-x^4}}$$

Comment: For the second one we get $$\frac{\frac{x^5 \log (4) \log
   (4096)}{\sqrt{2^{x^3}+1}}+x^2 \left(\frac{24 \log
   ^2(2)}{\sqrt{2^{x^3}+1}}-\log (2) \log
   (281474976710656)+\log (4) \log
   (16777216)\right)-\frac{\log
   ^2(4)}{\sqrt{2^{\sqrt{x}}+1}}+\frac{\log (2)
   \left(\log (256)-\frac{\log
   (16)}{\sqrt{2^{\sqrt{x}}+1}}\right)-\log (4) \log
   (16)}{\sqrt{x}}}{8 \log ^2(2)}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{u(x)}^{v(x)}h(t) dt=h\big(v(x)\big)v'(x)-h\big(u(x)\big)u'(x).$$

So
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{x^2}h(t) dt=h\big(x^2\big)\cdot 2x-h\big(0\big)\cdot0.=2xh(x^2)$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{\sqrt x}^{x^3}h(t) dt=h\big(x^3\big)\cdot 3x^2-h\big(\sqrt x\big)\cdot \frac{1}{2\sqrt x}=3x^2h(x^3)-\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}h\big(\sqrt x\big).$$

Comment: Kindly change the function to something other than $f(t)$, as $f(t)$ is already defined in the question.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Thanks!

Comment: Hi Basanta, thanks for the answer. Would you be so kind to tell me how the first formula of your answer is derived from the two corollaries of the fundamental theorem of calculus? I'm fairly new to calculus and can't see where that formula comes from. Thanks!

Comment: @Lafinur This formula is well known but the proof is long . Please see this Wikipedia page for explanation and proof https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: Thank you very much!